# Pygame ball movement flickering

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have been trying to make a basic Pygame code where the ball bounces around the screen and off your paddle. The paddle movement is smooth, but the ball flickers and is pretty choppy. Here is my complete code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random, time

pygame.init()

window = (800, 600)

background = (0, 0, 0)
back = pygame.Surface(window)
entity_color = (255, 255, 255)
x = 362.5
y = 550
ball_x = 387.5
ball_y = 50
width = 75
height = 25
clockobject = pygame.time.Clock()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window))

pygame.display.set_caption("Test Game")

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ball, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((25, 25))
        self.surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.dir_x = 1
        self.dir_y = 1
        self.speed = 2

    def update(self):
        global ball_x
        global ball_y
        if ball_x > 775:
            ball_x = 775
            ball.dir_x = -1
        elif ball_x < 0:
            ball_x = 0
            ball.dir_x = 1
        if ball_y < 0:
            ball_y = 0
            ball.dir_y = 1
        elif ball_y > 600:
            ball_y = 50
            ball_x = 387.5
        if ball_x <= x + 75 and ball_x >= x and ball_y <= y and ball_y >= y - 25:
            ball.dir_y = -1
        ball_x = ball_x + ball.speed * ball.dir_x
        ball_y = ball_y + ball.speed * ball.dir_y


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.image_s = pygame.image.load("paddle.png")
        self.image_b = self.image_s.get_rect()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 25))

        self.surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        global x
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x = x - 5
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x = x + 5

    def checkboundaries(self):
        global x
        if x > 725:
            x = 725
        if x < 0:
            x = 0

ball = Ball()
player = Player()
waiting = True
while waiting:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                running = True
                waiting = False
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
    player.update()
    ball.update()
    player.checkboundaries()
    screen.blit(back, (0,0))
    screen.blit(player.surf, (x, y))
    screen.blit(ball.surf, (ball_x, ball_y))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clockobject.tick(360)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Is this because of something wrong in my code that is running slowly, or am I missing something?

Comment: `ball.speed`? what happened to `self.speed`?

also use the `draw` function inside the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` in this case is `ball.draw` and use the proper surface name which is `self.image` instead of `self.surf`, and for movement use the `self.rect.center` to move, this way u can use the `draw` inside the `Sprite Class`

Comment: @CunningBard are you saying use .draw instead of .blit?

Comment: @EpicEfeathers Read about [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw). However, you can only use it if the attributes of the objects have the name `image` and `rect`. Furthermore `ball_x` and `ball_y` should be attributes instead of global variables. In the methods you should use `self` instead of `ball`.

Comment: @EpicEfeathers Anyway, the "flicker" is just an optical illusion because your frame rate is so high. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 but if I lower the frame rate the ball moves slower, and if I change the movement faster, it jumps. Is there nothing I can do then?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I will do that thank you.

Comment: also @Rabbid76 I lowered the frame rate to 60 and the flickering still happens. I also changed the ball_x etc. to attributes. Would the link you sent cut down on the flickering?

Comment: @EpicEfeathers This is just an optical illusion. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), you should also use [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Groupv).

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The latter delegates to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) — you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group. [...]

The former uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects — you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

e.g.:

```py
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
clockobject = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
back = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
pygame.display.set_caption("Test Game")

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ball, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((25, 25))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (387, 50))
        self.dir_x = 1
        self.dir_y = 1
        self.speed = 2

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.x > 775:
            self.rect.x = 775
            self.dir_x = -1
        elif self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
            self.dir_x = 1
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0
            self.dir_y = 1
        elif self.rect.y > 600:
            self.rect.topleft = (387, 50)
        if self.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
            ball.dir_y = -1
        self.rect.x += ball.speed * ball.dir_x
        self.rect.y += ball.speed * ball.dir_y

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((75, 25))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (363, 550))

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * 5
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())

ball = Ball()
player = Player()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([ball, player])

started = False
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                started = True
    
    
    screen.blit(back, (0,0))
    if started:
        all_sprites.update()
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clockobject.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```